# ¿Cómo repetir un bucle While para imprimir por pantalla un input?

Tags: python

Partiendo del siguiente pedazo de codigo:

```
verde = " se forma luego de combinar azul y amarillo"
naranja = "se forma luego de combinar rojo y amarillo"
color = str(input("introduce un color"))
if color == "verde": 
    print(f"El color {color}, {verde} ")
elif color == "naranja" 
     print(f"El color {color}, {naranja} ")
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que luego de que se imprima la respuesta de cómo se formaría el color, se le pregunte al usuario nuevamente la variable "color" o bien otro imput que pregunte nuevamente si quiere consultar como formar otro color.

Que la primera vez el usuario quiera saber como se forma el verde y luego quiera saber como se forma el naranja, o el marron, etc. y se le pueda seguir mostrando el input hasta que responda NO o FIN.

al final, tendria que haber algun mensaje del tipo. Si no quiere saber mas colores presione tal cosa y se termina el programa.

Entiendo que hay que usar un while pero no encuentro ninguna explicación satisfactoria en youtube.

Comment: crea un diccionario cuya clave sea el color y el valor la frase, luego solo iteras en el diccionario

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un diccionario cuya clave sea el color y el valor la frase, luego solo accedes al diccionario.

```py
colores = {
    "verde": " se forma luego de combinar azul y amarillo",
    "naranja": "se forma luego de combinar rojo y amarillo"
}
while True:
    #siempre devuelve un string
    color = input("introduce un color").strip() #quitamos los espacios en blanco del principio y final
    if not color: break
    elif color in colores: 
        print(f"El color {color}, {colores[color]} ")
    else: 
        print(f"Aun no tenemos la combinación del color {color}")
```

Comment: Ok, pero el problema es que luego de que se muestre El color "verde" se forma luego de combinar azul y amarillo, yo necesito que se repita la pregunta. que la persona puede ingresar otro color. y si no quiere ingresar mas colores, que detengan la ejecucion.

Comment: pues metelo en un `while`

Comment: ok, pero no se como se hace. solo vi usar while para numeros cuando son menores a algo. no entiendo como funcionariran con una variable o un diccionario

Comment: edite la respuesta ._: